# How to create new commands in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Just like ipconfig, when typed in batch it executes a command, so how do I make a new command, without using CALL, and can be executed anywhere, not just that path.
So just like that this code-

```
@echo off
color fc
echo Example
echo :--:
pause
```

Can be executed by this command

> EXEM

If you can help, thanks.

Comment: Save the code as EXEM.bat and put it somewhere in your PATH.

Comment: Without using CALL???

Comment: Yes, without using the `call` command.

Comment: If you want to create new commands that may be called _inside a Batch file_, then you must use a _compiler_ of a programming language and create an executable file with .exe extension, like `ipconfig.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your `EXEM.BAT` file as normal, then convert it to `EXEM.EXE` with something like [this](http://www.f2ko.de/downloads/Bat_To_Exe_Converter.zip) bat to exe converter.

You can then put it somewhere in your `%Path%` and it will run when running `EXEM` from `CMD`, without terminating execution.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried on Win8 and after executing, the bat file terminates with no further commands executed.

Comment: I mean something like

`:: A.BAT`
`echo 1`
`B`
`echo 3`

`:: B.BAT`
`echo 2`


Executing `A` results printing
`1`
`2`

Comment: The user wrote the command as `EXEM`, not as `call EXEM`, plus, explicitly asked for a solution _without using CALL_.